# c# to Access INSERT INTO query not working

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010

I am trying to enter the value of a textbox in c# into a field in a database that I have in access. For some reason I keep getting the error saying:

'An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

Can't quite see what is wrong, this is the first time I have attempted to do this in a project so I am not too experienced with it. This is my code:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION STRING GOES HERE);

connection.Open();

string playerName = textBox[i].Text;
string query = "INSERT INTO (TotalPlayerName)(Player Name) VALUES(" + playerName + ")";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

if it helps then the database is called 'Database' the table is called 'TotalPlayerName' and the field is called 'Player Name'

Comment: a) use parameters  -- really, but if you are going to use naked strings then you need to enclose string values in single quotes. "INSERT INTO TotalPlayerName (Player Name) VALUES('" + playerName + "')";

Comment: why is it so difficult for individuals to use `Google` @Alby you could have found your answer quite easily by doing a google search on how to construct INSERT Statement SQL` also use the debugger.. show all relevant code and show us what the connection string looks like.. wrap your `ExecuteNonQuery` around a try{}catch{}

Comment: been searching for the answer for a couple days actually, most have given me the query for SQL and not access etc, I wouldnt have posted in here if I hadnt looked before.

Answer (score 3):

The correct code to do your task is

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO TotalPlayerName ([Player Name]) VALUES(?)";

using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(...))
using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection))
{
   connection.Open();
   command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = textBox[i].Text;
   int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if(result > 0)
      MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
   else
      MessageBox.Show("Failure to insert");
}
```

This approach fixes three problems:

- The connection and the command object should be disposed at the end
  (see using statement)
- Every value that you need to pass to the query should be passed as
  parameter
- If a field name (or table name) has embedded spaces you should enclose
  it between square brackets

(The messages below the ExecuteNonQuery are there only as an example to check the return value of ExecuteNonQuery)
Remember also that if your table has more than this field and some of the other fields don't accept null values you should provide some value also for them. 
For example

```
string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO TotalPlayerName ([Player Name], FieldB) 
                 VALUES(?, ?)";

command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = textBox[i].Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = "ValueForFieldB";
```

Just remember to strictly follow the order of the ? when you add your parameter values

Comment: (+1) from me since you corrected many issues that the initial code had and you caught me while I was writing about them :) So there isn't any reason to rewrite them in my answer.

Comment: still not working for me, do I need to add more '?' for the other fields in the table? the field I'm looking to insert it into is the 2nd if that helps

Comment: If your table has more than this field (excluding Autonumber columns) and these fields don't accept NULL values then you need to provide some value for them. Check the structure of your table in MS-Access for any field with the Required property set to Yes